# TypeError when creating a date object

Tags: python, date, datetime, integer

I'm trying to create a `datetime.date` object from integers, this is my code:

```
datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)
```

It gives me this error:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'
```

Comment: Hint: Are you doing `from datetime import datetime` or `import datetime`? (I'm guessing the former...)

Comment: `>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date(2011,1,1)
datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)` no problem, I don't understand. If you do `from datetime import datetime`, you're actually calling `datetime.datetime.date(2011,1,1)`, which will fail.

Comment: hi Thanks a lot folks. The problem is that I did from datetime import datetime. so datetime.date is fine, but datetime.datetime.date obviously is not. thanx again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do the following, it'll work neatly:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date(2011,1,1)
datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)
```

However, if you do this:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

and then

```
datetime.date(2011,1,1)
```

the method you're actually calling is `datetime.datetime.date(2011,1,1)`, which will fail:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.date(2011,1,1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'
```

Answer (score 3):

answer, based on the very generous contributions above.

The problem is that the datetime library includes a datetime class, which to the uninitiated sometimes is confusing.

To wrap up, if you do:

```
import datetime
datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)
```

you get

```
>>> datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)
```

Since you are using the date class of the datetime library. However, if you do

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)
```

you will get

```
>>>TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'
```

since you are (inadvertently) using the datetime class of the datetime library, which equates to:

```
datetime.datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)
```

and the datetime class of the datetime library has no date method

Answer (score 1):

Just use the proper `import` and you're set:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> today = date.today()
>>> today
datetime.date(2016, 3, 4)
>>> date(2016, 3, 4)
datetime.date(2016, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error might be due to your `import statement`.

Change it from:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

To:

```
import datetime
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date = datetime(year=2011,month=1,day=1)
>>> print date
2011-01-01 00:00:00
>>>
```

Official documentation: [`datetime` Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)